# How to subtract Day from string in typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need help to subtract one day from `endDate` - but `endDate` is string.

Tried with with this:

```
moment(this.endDate).subtract(1, 'day').format()
```

does not work.

```
 public ngOnChanges(): void {
    const startDate = this.startDate ? moment(this.startDate).format() : moment().startOf('day').format();
    const endDate = this.endDate ? moment(this.endDate).format() : moment(startDate).endOf('day').format();
    this.datePicker = new DatePicker(startDate, endDate);
    this.setDatePicker();

    if (this.continiousDatesValue !== null) {
        this.continiousDatesValueMoment = moment(this.continiousDatesValue);
    }
    if (this.previousDatesValue !== null) {
        this.previousDatesValueMoment = moment(this.previousDatesValue);
    }
}
```

Also here I should subtract one day from "endDate" - which is string:

```
private onDatesChange(): void {
        this.startDateChange.emit(this.datePicker.startDate);
        this.endDateChange.emit(this.datePicker.endDate);
        this.startEndDateChange.emit({startDate: this.datePicker.startDate, endDate: this.datePicker.endDate});
        this.isOpen = false;
    }
```

Comment: can share the sample string of date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the subtracted date to the date Object

```js
let endDate = "2018-04-01 08:14:00";
let dateOb = new Date(endDate);
dateOb.setDate(dateOb.getDate() - 1);
console.log(dateOb);
// now you can use moment to parse to your desired format
//or 

endDate = dateOb.getFullYear() + "-" + ('0' + (dateOb.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ('0' + dateOb.getDate()).slice(-2) + " " + ('0' + dateOb.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" + ('0' + dateOb.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" + ( '0' + dateOb.getSeconds()).slice(-2);

// getMonth() starts from 0.


console.log(endDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

momentjs expects date either in MM DD YYYY format or YYYY MM DD for manipulation.
So provide date in similar format, or you can use solution proposed by Ashish Ranjan.